# How would I open a modal to allow a user to select what component to add?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app that creates a widget layout where they can add and remove widgets in a grid of 4. Currently in the addEvent I have it defaulted to add the "DataTable" component.Instead, I want it to open a modal from which they can select from the "DataTable" or "CheckboxList" component and a larger list of components later on. I am new to react and not exactly sure how to implement this, any help would be great.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Swappable from './components/SwappableComponent'
import './App.css';
import DataTable from './components/tableWidget';
import CheckboxList from './components/CheckboxList';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";



const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  }
});

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={
        widgets:[
          {id:1, content: <DataTable/>},
          {id:2, content: <CheckboxList/>},
          {id:3, content: ""},
          {id:4, content: ""}
        ]
      }

    }  
    deleteEvent=(index)=>{
        const copyWidgets=Object.assign([],this.state.widgets);
        let widget=this.state.widgets[index];
        widget.content="";
        copyWidgets[index]=widget;
        this.setState({
            widgets:copyWidgets
        })
    }
    addEvent=(index)=>{
        const copyWidgets=Object.assign([],this.state.widgets);
        let widget=this.state.widgets[index];
        widget.content=<DataTable/>;
        copyWidgets[index]=widget;
        this.setState({
            widgets:copyWidgets
        })
    }
    render() {
      const { classes } = this.props;

      return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
            {
                this.state.widgets.map((widget,index)=>{
                    return(
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                            <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id={widget.id} content={widget.content} delete={this.deleteEvent.bind(this,index)} add={this.addEvent.bind(this,index)}/></Paper>
                         </Grid>
                    )
                })
            }
        </Grid>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }

  App.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: Modal in react, is just another `Component`, for example follow this article on how to build modal in react. https://alligator.io/react/modal-component/

Comment: You can use Bootstrap modal, this make a program pattern to your application,  [doc here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/)

Answer (score 1):

The basics of a modal component is below. You can add header and footer sections, fade-in effects, opacity on background etc - go crazy

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { display, close, children } = this.props;
    if (!display) return null;
    return (
      <div className="modal">
        {children}
        <button onClick={close}>Close</button>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

// css

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
 }
 
 // use it
 <Modal display={this.state.displayModal}
  close={()=>this.setState({displayModal: false})} >
   // add your modal content here
   <h1>Add Event</h1>
   <p>Some relevant jsx here</p>
 </Modal>
```

to initiate the modal you just set `displayModal` to `true`:

```
addEvent = () => {
  this.setState({displayModal:true});
}
```

Comment: How would I connect this to the addEvent so that the user can choose what component they want to add, and thanks!

Comment: nw - you'd pass in some child components and call setState in addEvent to bring up the popup - Ill amend

Comment: I implemented a modal but I am having trouble with the functionality if you could help I linked the updated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478740/how-to-select-component-to-display-based-on-option-clicked